# Como hacer este tipo de dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo un dataframe con las columnas id y code lo que quiero hacer es una nueva Columna (parent)que me muestre el primer valor un 0 y el o los siguientes que muestre la id que tiene la fila del que tiene el valor 0 . Algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que en la columna `parent` tienes ceros en ciertas posiciones arbitrarias (y lo que haya en el resto de posiciones, que no son ceros, es irrelevante porque se va a sobreescribir).

Por tanto comienzo por generar un dataframe como el descrito (en este caso relleno con `125` los valores irrelevantes, y pongo "a mano" ceros en ciertos lugares para que los datos sean como lo que has mostrado).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": list(range(1,10)), "parent": [125]*9})
for i in (1, 4, 8):
   df.loc[i-1, "parent"] = 0
print(df)
```

---

```html
   id  parent
0   1       0
1   2     125
2   3     125
3   4       0
4   5     125
5   6     125
6   7     125
7   8       0
8   9     125
```

El problema ahora se enunciaría así:

> **En la columna "parent" rellenar todos los valores distintos de 0 con el id del último 0 que haya aparecido antes.**

Para resolver el problema añado otra columna auxiliar que luego borraré. Y en ella hago lo siguiente:

- Relleno con None la columna auxiliar
- En los lugares en los que "parent" es igual a 0, copio el valor de id a la columna auxiliar. Eso me dejará de momento un dataframe así:

  ```html
     id parent   aux
  0   1      0     1
  1   2    125  None
  2   3    125  None
  3   4      0     4
  4   5    125  None
  5   6    125  None
  6   7    125  None
  7   8      0     8
  8   9    125  None
  ```
- Finalmente uso `fillna()` sobre esa columna con el método "ffill". Eso sustituirá todos los None (o NaN) de la columna aux con el último valor observado en esa columna distinto de None (o NaN).
- La columna aux resultante es lo que querías, así que la copio a la columna parent (a los lugares distintos de 0) y elimino la columna aux.

Todo eso son cuatro líneas de código:

```
df["aux"] = None
df.loc[df.parent==0, "aux"] = df.id
df.loc[df.parent!=0, "parent"] = df.aux.fillna(method="ffill")
df = df.drop(columns="aux")
```

Y el resultado:

```
   id  parent
0   1       0
1   2       1
2   3       1
3   4       0
4   5       4
5   6       4
6   7       4
7   8       0
8   9       8
```

## Actualización

Parece ser (a la vista del comentario) que los 0 en la columna parent no eran datos de entrada, sino que había que rellenarlos también a partir del contenido de la columna "code" (los ceros irían en las filas en las que el "code" cambia). De modo que adapto la respuesta con esta información y tratando de reutilizar lo ya explicado antes.

Empezamos por crear un dataframe en el que no hay columna `parent`, solo los "id" y los "code":

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": list(range(1,10)), "code": ["987556"]*3+["99900"]*4+["88077"]*2})
print(df)
```

---

```html
   id    code
0   1  987556
1   2  987556
2   3  987556
3   4   99900
4   5   99900
5   6   99900
6   7   99900
7   8   88077
8   9   88077
```

Creamos ahora un par de columnas adicionales llamadas `"parent"` y `"aux"`, ambas con valores iniciales `None` en todas las filas:

```
df["aux"] = None
df["parent"] = None
```

y ahora viene una parte interesante. Vamos a encontrar en qué filas el valor de "code" cambia. Esos son los lugares donde habría que poner ceros en la columna "parent". Para encontrar esto comparamos lo que hay en la columna "code" con lo que hay en esa misma columna, pero desplazado (usando `.shift()`). Eso dará una columna de booleanos que tendrán `True` en las filas en las que el code ha cambiado, y `False` en aquellas en las que se repite el valor de la fila anterior. Esto falla en la primera fila, pues no tiene fila anterior, y para esa tenemos que meter artificalmente un `True`:

```
cambios = (df.code.shift() != df.code)
cambios[0] = True
```

Ahora usamos esa columna de booleanos como índice para poner ceros en la columna "parent", y de paso para poner el valor del id en la columna "aux":

```
df.loc[cambios, "parent"] = 0
df.loc[cambios, "aux"] = df.id
```

Ahora mismo `df` está así:

```html
   id    code   aux parent
0   1  987556     1      0
1   2  987556  None   None
2   3  987556  None   None
3   4   99900     4      0
4   5   99900  None   None
5   6   99900  None   None
6   7   99900  None   None
7   8   88077     8      0
8   9   88077  None   None
```

y ahora podemos aplicar los trucos explicados en la primera parte de la respuesta, para rellenar los None de la columna "aux" usando `"ffill"`, y asignar esos valores a la columna "parent", pero sólo en aquellos lugares en los que no hubo cambios (usando `~cambios` como índice, ya que `~` actúa como operador de negación).

Es decir:

```
df.loc[~cambios, "parent"] = df.aux.ffill()
```

Tras esto ya podemos eliminar la columna auxiliar y obtener el resultado:

```
df = df.drop(columns="aux")
print(df)
```

---

```html
  id    code parent
0   1  987556      0
1   2  987556      1
2   3  987556      1
3   4   99900      0
4   5   99900      4
5   6   99900      4
6   7   99900      4
7   8   88077      0
8   9   88077      8
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirve bastante y perdón por lo vago  que fue la explicación del ejercicio. La verdad es que el 0 se muestra en la primera fila en donde aparezca un nuevo código en la columna ‘code’. Es por eso que la primera fila es 0 y las otras son la id

Comment: Ah, entiendo. He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias, es lo que estaba buscando. Se agradece la ayuda.

Comment: De nada. Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha resuelto el problema.